# listen to android calendar events

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent, google-calendar-api

im about to create an android application that do some actions and profile changing silent/vibration/ringing based on event, the user add the event date and time and chose a profie for this event, the event will be stored on the google calendar which will be sync autmaticlly to the android calendar, so what i want is , i need to listen to the android calendar events so when an event time occured, i check it and check my database and see which profile is for this event and run it or which action i should do, so again my point is
to listen to the calendar events when time occured, anyone can help me with that?

or in another words get the event id from the calendar when this event just happend

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you can listen to Android Calendar. You will have to use the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html) to retrieve the events for the user.
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2Fcalendar-android-sample) is a sample that uses Calendar API with Android.

I would suggest that you retrieve some of the future events. You can do it periodically say every day or every hour. Sync from the Calendar API instead of the Android Calendar.
Now in your database store the time and action to be taken and when ever an event occurs perform the action.

Comment: ya but what if the user deleted an event from the calendar before my sync period occured? it will give wrong results

Comment: There will always be some things you cannot control. But currently no Google API can be made to to give your app notifications. You will have to poll the Google servers for updates.